# How to move to Specific user profile screen from a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of User which the list become from a model class

```
final Consultant giovanni = Consultant(
    id: 6,
    consultantFirstName: 'Giovanni',
    consultantLastName: 'Racchi',
    consultantNickName: 'Ragoni Dreams',
    consultantCategory: 'Amore',
    consultantDescription: 'Ciao a tutti sono Giovanni',
    consultantImageProfile: 'assets/images/giovanni.jpg',
    consultantLikes: '4896',
    consultantReviews: '76345',
    consultantPrice: '4.55',
  consultantExperience: '16',);
List<Consultant> consultant = [
  marco,
  carmela,
  sabrina,
  saverio,
  pamela,
  giovanni
];
```

into my list I have Gesture Detector which should move to the right profile when clicking on the right card profile where `ConsultantProfile` screen is called

```
 ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          itemCount: consultant.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => ConsultantProfile(
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 15,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
```

obviously at the moment when clicking on a item of the list it moves to the first User Profile, but how to move to the right profile User when a specific Card User is Clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make your `ConsultantProfile` to take in an argument of `Consultant`
as shown below

```
class ConsultantProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConsultantProfile({Key key, this.cosnsultant}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ConsultantProfileState createState() => _ConsultantProfileState();
  final Cosnsultant cosnsultant;
}

class _ConsultantProfileState extends State<ConsultantProfile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(widget.cosnsultant. consultantFirstName),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//using stateless widget

```
    class ConsultantProfile extends StatelessWidget {
   
    final Cosnsultant cosnsultant;  
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(this.cosnsultant. consultantFirstName),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

and then during navigation do parse your argument

```
 GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => ConsultantProfile(
                       consultant:consultant[index],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Ofc this way will work also with `StatelessWidget`. You can add an sample example also.